# listview not getting data correctly

Tags: java, android, listview

okay, so i got a listView in my android app to display messages, everything has been going good ever since i got help on time but now i got a bug where the last message wont show.

the message part wont show if its a "system" message. this is linked to firebase.

but when i get the data it all works good for each item besides for the type of message.

```
// this is what the message looks like in the database 
  "messages": "hi",
  "number": "1",
  "pfp": "",
  "time": "2022-04-22T00:39:00.520Z",

// this tells the app what type of message it is
  "type": "user",


  "user_uid": "user id",
  "username": "frugalnormal"
```

even switched to the recycleview and same thing

note: i just put a toast to tell me if it thinks the message is system and sure enough every time[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMU1y.png) i send a "user" message it tells me that its a system message and wont show that part but can still show the time

also the time is supposed to appear over a text message

**Update:**
okay so I've tired pretty much everything now the last message shows but the app still thinks the last message is always a "system" message

And also so the switch returns both somehow
"User" and "system" for some reason

**update2:**
So now I'm really confused, scrolling through it makes the system message thing happen randomly on different messages

**UPDATE 3**
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CODE FOR THE WHOLE ADAPTER:

this is for applying the data to the view:

```js
 _ch_child_listener = new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot _param1, String _param2) {
                GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                final String _childKey = _param1.getKey();
                final HashMap<String, Object> _childValue = _param1.getValue(_ind);
                ch.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot _dataSnapshot) {
                        lop = new ArrayList<>();
                        try {
                            GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>> _ind = new GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String, Object>>() {};
                            for (DataSnapshot _data : _dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                HashMap<String, Object> _map = _data.getValue(_ind);
                                lop.add(_map);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception _e) {
                            _e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        listview2.setAdapter(new Listview2Adapter(lop));
                        ((BaseAdapter)listview2.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                        x.add(_childKey);
                    }
```

and here is the rest:

```js
public class Listview2Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;

    public Listview2Adapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr) {
        _data = _arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Object> getItem(int _index) {
        return _data.get(_index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int _index) {
        return _index;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
        LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View _view = _v;
        if (_view == null) {
            _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.messgebubble, listview2, false);
        }

        final LinearLayout time = _view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        final TextView textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final LinearLayout linear4 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear4);
        final TextView timetext = _view.findViewById(R.id.timetext);
        final LinearLayout left = _view.findViewById(R.id.left);
        final LinearLayout linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        final de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView circleimageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.circleimageview1);
        final TextView message = _view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        final ImageView imageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        final TextView SystemText = _view.findViewById(R.id.systemtext);
        final LinearLayout system = _view.findViewById(R.id.system);


        Instant i = Instant.parse(_data.get(_position).get("time").toString());
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());;
        String Time = dateTimeFormatter.format(i);
        timetext.setText(Time);

        String messageType = lop.get(_position).get("type").toString();


        switch (messageType){
            case "system":

                SystemText.setText(_data.get(_position).get("messages").toString());

                Toast.makeText(GroupChatActiviy.this, "This is a system message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                system.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                break;
            case "user":
                linear4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (_data.get((int)_position).get("messages").toString().equals("")) {

                    if (_data.get((int)_position).containsKey("image")) {
                        imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                            linear4.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            linear1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }
                        else {
                            linear4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            linear1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                else {
                    message.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("messages").toString());
                    message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (lop.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        linear4.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        linear1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
                    }
                    else {
                        linear4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        linear1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right);
                    }
                    if (_data.get((int)_position).containsKey("image")) {
                        imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }

                String LastTimeText = _data.get((int)_position - 1).get("time").toString();
                Instant LastI = Instant.parse(LastTimeText);
                Duration Dur = Duration.between(LastI, i);
                if (Dur.getSeconds() <= 600) {

                }
                else {
                    if (lop.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                    }
                    else {
                        circleimageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("pfp").toString())).into(circleimageview1);
                        textview1.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("username").toString());
                    }
                    time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }


                break;

        }

        if(_data.get((int)_position).get("number") != null){
            if (_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString().equals("")) {

         }
            else {
                if (Numberrr < Double.parseDouble(_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString())) {
                 Numberrr = Double.parseDouble(_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString()) + 1;
              }
           }
        }


        return _view;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you may be missing `system.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: Sorry for no context but system is the linear layout for the system message and shouldn't be enabled unless its a system message.

Comment: Is that not the type of message that is not showing?

Comment: Its the user message, the system one shows fine. And its always the last text that doesnt show.

Comment: With your latest update, it sounds like there may be something wrong with your adapter. Can you include more of the code around the snippet already provided? It looks like you are parsing your data source for each view rather than parsing it once and passing in the data to the adapter in a collection.

Comment: added to post, and thank you for trying to help me here, i greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your adapter is based on `_data` but the message type is being grabbed from `lop`. These two can periodically get out of sync as new data comes in. Make sure your adapter is only accessing row item information from `_data` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will fix my code real quick and see if it works

Comment: So this was only part of my problem, now only the last message shows both instead of it being random

Comment: I will search through my code to see if I find a reason why this is still happening

Comment: Okay scrolling up and down seems to break it,  something with the data of the view, maybe its the way I added the data or something?

Comment: Could you describe how it breaks? One other thing I noticed in your code is you are always setting a new adapter. You only need to set the adapter once. Since the collection is passed by reference, you can add the value and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Okay so that fixed my problem with the last message and since that's what I was asking I'll accept it as an answer. But now I got a new problem on my hand. Scrolling up and down in the listview leads to the messages changing if it's a system message or not

Comment: Like the first system message is " (group name) has been created. And once I start scrolling through the view it starts popping up on some of the other view and changes everytime when scrolling back and fourth

Comment: **UPDATE** I found out deleting or adding message fixes the glitch. But scrolling breaks it

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get past the initial issue. Views are reused, so make sure you are properly setting all state on each getView() call.

Comment: Also another thing I found out, it only breaks when a system message is in view, then it starts to make other messages a system message once I start scrolling

Comment: Yes that is indicative of the system message block setting something that is not undone by the user message block.

Comment: When your saying block, are you referring to the switch statement?

Comment: Yes. You are being handed a view that used to hold a system message and need to convert it to a user message. There is something happening in the system message state that the user state isn't addressing.

Comment: I fixed it, thank you so much for the help. So what I did was make the system message visibility = GONE when it was a user message. This might be a temporary fix but its working

Comment: That sounds like the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be of visibility, whenever item render we should always hide everything like you can create group `user` and `system` and at first hide all views of it.on every bind view we will first hide everything and depending open the data will make particular all view visible and then do data setup.

Do on thing like below code in you adapter's get View method

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View getView(final int _position, View _v, ViewGroup _container) {
        LayoutInflater _inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View _view = _v;
        if (_view == null) {
            _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.messgebubble, listview2, false);
        }

        final LinearLayout time = _view.findViewById(R.id.time);
        final TextView textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        final LinearLayout linear4 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear4);
        final TextView timetext = _view.findViewById(R.id.timetext);
        final LinearLayout left = _view.findViewById(R.id.left);
        final LinearLayout linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        final de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView circleimageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.circleimageview1);
        final TextView message = _view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        final ImageView imageview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
        final TextView SystemText = _view.findViewById(R.id.systemtext);
        final LinearLayout system = _view.findViewById(R.id.system);


        time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linear4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timetext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        linear1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        circleimageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        SystemText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        system.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Instant i = Instant.parse(_data.get(_position).get("time").toString());
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());;
        String Time = dateTimeFormatter.format(i);
        timetext.setText(Time);

        String messageType = lop.get(_position).get("type").toString();


        switch (messageType){
            case "system":

                SystemText.setText(_data.get(_position).get("messages").toString());

                Toast.makeText(GroupChatActiviy.this, "This is a system message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                system.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                break;
            case "user":
                linear4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (_data.get((int)_position).get("messages").toString().equals("")) {

                    if (_data.get((int)_position).containsKey("image")) {
                        imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        if (_data.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                            linear4.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                            linear1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        }
                        else {
                            linear4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                            linear1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                else {
                    message.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("messages").toString());
                    message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (lop.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {
                        linear4.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        linear1.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);
                    }
                    else {
                        linear4.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        linear1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        linear1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right);
                    }
                    if (_data.get((int)_position).containsKey("image")) {
                        imageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }

                String LastTimeText = _data.get((int)_position - 1).get("time").toString();
                Instant LastI = Instant.parse(LastTimeText);
                Duration Dur = Duration.between(LastI, i);
                if (Dur.getSeconds() <= 600) {

                }
                else {
                    if (lop.get((int)_position).get("user_uid").toString().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())) {

                    }
                    else {
                        circleimageview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textview1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Uri.parse(_data.get((int)_position).get("pfp").toString())).into(circleimageview1);
                        textview1.setText(_data.get((int)_position).get("username").toString());
                    }
                    time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }


                break;

        }

        if(_data.get((int)_position).get("number") != null){
            if (_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString().equals("")) {

         }
            else {
                if (Numberrr < Double.parseDouble(_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString())) {
                 Numberrr = Double.parseDouble(_data.get((int)_position).get("number").toString()) + 1;
              }
           }
        }


        return _view;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, and report back if it has/hasnt worked. But anyways I should set it up like that since it makes more sense

Comment: So it helped show the message but now it thinks its both messages, like the switch executes both pieces of code for some reason

Comment: sorry , didn't get can you show updated code?

Comment: its now in the last code snip it, its the entire adapter since someone else requested it. and its after all the finals

Comment: Please check my updated answer can you try that?

Comment: So I've done this in the xml itself, so it would not have to disable just to enable, since they are already disabled

Comment: And now I can confirm its something to do with the code, I use a toast to tell me when a system message appears and it seems to be the last message thinks it's a "user" and "system" message. And now every message is randomly doing that